# how to get text from radio button to snippet

Tags: java, android

Hello I am beginner in android and java
and I am trying to get the text from radio buttons to snippet off relevant marker.
The app is working but is does not show the text or the snippet.
I've tried using different methods and couldn't make it work
please help

```
   if (parsable) {
    String currentStatus;
    LatLng targetLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
    Log.e("GPS", "onClick: lat:" + lat + " lon:" + lon);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(targetLatLng).title(strTitle);
    markerOptions.snippet("current status : "+currentStatus);

    if (radioButtonView1==currentStatus)
    {
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(targetLatLng));

    }
    else if (currentStatus==radioButtonView2)
    {
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(targetLatLng));
    }
    else if (currentStatus==radioButtonView3)
    {
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(targetLatLng));
    }
    else if (currentStatus==radioButtonView4)
    {
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(targetLatLng));
    }
    else if (currentStatus==radioButtonView5)
    {
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(targetLatLng));
    }
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(targetLatLng));
```

Comment: Where are you setting `currentStatus`? In that code example it'll always be `null`.

Comment: tnx for the quick response, i just added snipet to marker inside each if, and it worked